# Elassandra Node failing to start

Tags: amazon-ec2, cassandra, cassandra-3.0, elassandra

We are building `Elassandra` Cluster on a Single `AWS` Region with the DC being spread over 3 AZ(s). We are using `ec2snitch` and facing the following exception while starting the 2nd node in the cluster. The 1st one comes up fine. Version used is `Elassandra 5.5.0.24`

```
2018-11-09 03:22:38,945 INFO  [main] org.elassandra.discovery.CassandraDiscovery.doStart(CassandraDiscovery.java:152) localNode name=10.XX.YY.ZZZ id=<<UUID>> localAddress=/10.XX.YY.ZZZ publish_host=10.XX.YY.ZZZ:1234
{5.5.0}: Initialization Failed ...
- NullPointerException[null]
2018-11-09 03:22:38,949 ERROR [main] org.apache.cassandra.service.ElassandraDaemon.main(ElassandraDaemon.java:588) Exception
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at org.elassandra.discovery.CassandraDiscovery.updateClusterGroupsFromGossiper(CassandraDiscovery.java:286)
        at org.elassandra.discovery.CassandraDiscovery.doStart(CassandraDiscovery.java:172)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.component.AbstractLifecycleComponent.start(AbstractLifecycleComponent.java:69)
        at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.start(Node.java:757)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.ElassandraDaemon.activate(ElassandraDaemon.java:232)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.ElassandraDaemon.main(ElassandraDaemon.java:551)
```

Comment: Hi, has this problem been resolved ? I would investigate otherwise

Comment: Tracked @ https://github.com/strapdata/elassandra/issues/236